# X-Forwarded-For 127.0.0.6 when using IPv6

Tags: curl, http-headers, ipv6, apache2.4

I'm using mod_remoteip with Apache 2.4 to assign the X-Forwarded-For header to the client ip field to properly log the client ip while I'm behind a loadbalancer. The loadbalancer adds the X-Forwaded-For header to each request and accesses the webservers always through IPv6.

As you can see in the following tests the IPv6 requests are just showing the 127.0.0.6 as client IP instead of the real client ip when coming through IPv6 from external. With IPv4 this works just fine.

The loadbancers IP is `2a02:2e0:40c:102::5`

The webservers IP is `2a02:2e0:40c:102:1::10`

My clients address are `5.199.135.102` + `2001:4ba0:ffff:ea::5`

**IPv6 request**

`curl -6 http://foo.bar/ -I`

**Request / Response on network level on the webserver**

```
####
T 2a02:2e0:40c:102::5:41974 -> 2a02:2e0:40c:102:1::10:80 [AP]
HEAD / HTTP/1.1.
User-Agent: curl/7.29.0.
Host: foo.bar.
Accept: */*.
X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.6.
Via: 1.1 [2a02:2e0:40c:ffff::3]:80.
X-Forwarded-For-Port: 57252.
.
##
T 2a02:2e0:40c:102:1::10:80 -> 2a02:2e0:40c:102::5:41974 [AP]
HTTP/1.1 302 Found.
Date: Tue, 30 Aug 2016 21:44:13 GMT.
Server: Apache.
Location: https://foo.bar/.
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1.
.
```

**Apache log output IPv6**

`"127.0.0.6" 2a02:2e0:40c:102::5 - - [31/Aug/2016:00:07:15 +0200] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "curl/7.29.0"`

**IPv4 request**

`curl -4 http://foo.bar/ -I`

**Request / Response on network level on the webserver**

```
####
T 2a02:2e0:40c:102::5:21050 -> 2a02:2e0:40c:102:1::10:80 [AP]
HEAD / HTTP/1.1.
User-Agent: curl/7.29.0.
Host: foo.bar.
Accept: */*.
Via: 1.1 1.2.3.4:80.
X-Forwarded-For: 5.199.135.102.
X-Forwarded-For-Port: 56352.
.

##
T 2a02:2e0:40c:102:1::10:80 -> 2a02:2e0:40c:102::5:21050 [AP]
HTTP/1.1 302 Found.
Date: Tue, 30 Aug 2016 22:06:08 GMT.
Server: Apache.
Location: https://foo.bar/.
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1.
.
.
```

**Apache log output IPv4**

`"5.199.135.102" 2a02:2e0:40c:102::5 - - [31/Aug/2016:00:06:08 +0200] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "curl/7.29.0"`

Did anyone had this issue before? Let me know if you need further information.

THX in advance - mat1010

Comment: This question is off-topic here. When posting this on another website please provide information on the load balancer. That is the device that gives you the wrong information and your question doesn't give any information about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the issue was `mod_remoteip`.

The loadbalancer masquerades IPv6 addresses whith brackets like this in the via header
`Via: 1.1 [2a02:2e0:40c:ffff::3]:80`

This is part of the [RFC7239](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239) IPv6 address notation due to the fact that it's sometimes necassary to specify the port which is also seperated by a colon.

`mod_remoteip` is not able to interpret such addresses. This has been also noted below [`mod_remoteip` documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_remoteip.html) within the apache devel version by Lee Maguire.

> I assume that mod_remoteip does not currently support RFC 7239 syntax
> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239
>
> X-Forwarded-For: 192.0.2.43, 2001:db8:cafe::17
>
> becomes:
>
> Forwarded: for=192.0.2.43, for="[2001:db8:cafe::17]"